# How to check if an integer is a perfect square

Tags: java, drjava, perfect-square

How could I write an if-then statement that checks if an inputted integer is a perfect square or not (i.e. if I took the square root, it would be an integer as well: 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, etc.) in DrJava? Thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am aware that this question already has an answer.... But just in case, this also works.

```
int x = (int) Math.sqrt(input);
if(Math.pow(x,2) == input)
    //Do stuff
```

Comment: Would the "int" before x and the "int" in the parentheses be my integer as well?

Comment: no. Just replace `yourIntHere`.

Comment: Also, is there a way to negate that? As in saying if "int is _not_ a perfect square."

Comment: just add `else` block after `if` and add your code in that `else` block.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much you've been a big help!! :D