# How do I find perfect square from a set of numbers in Java?

Tags: java, perfect-square

So I'm trying to find out the perfect squares within a set of numbers. I declared the necessary variables, added a for loop, added a `sqroot = Math.sqrt(num)` and a print method to list the numbers. What I can't figure out is how can I make the program pick out the perfect squares within the range of numbers, and find the average of them?

This is for an assignment I'm working on for a class and I've been stuck on this for a while now. I'm also rather new to Java so sorry if this is a stupid question. The code is below:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        double sqroot = 0;
        int sumPsq = 0; //sum variable
        int psq = 0; //counter for perfect squares
        double avg = 0;

        for(num = 101; num <= 149; num += 2){
           sqroot = Math.sqrt(num);

            if(sqroot*sqroot == num){ //Condition to find perfect squares
                psq += 1; //counting perfect squares
                sumPsq = sumPsq + num; //Find the sum of all the perfect squares

                System.out.println(num); //Print out the perfect squares
            }
        }
        avg = 1.0 * sumPsq/psq;
        System.out.println(avg);
    }

}
```

This is just a piece of the code from the entire assignment, so if you need more of it then I'm more than willing to provide it. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably either put the perfect squares you find in a list, or just sum them and keep a counter of how many there are.

Comment: Your code seems to be doing exactly what you said you needed it to be doing, though that's really not the best way of testing for perfect-squaredness....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056609/how-to-check-if-an-integer-is-a-perfect-square

Comment: lets start analyzing the problem: what is the exact definition of a perfect square?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas If this code gets the answer right, it's only by accident, because OP is never rounding the square root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perfect square is a number that can be expressed as the product of two equal integers so it must be an int after the sqrt. If you do a `sqroot*sqroot == num` you are just checking that sqrt is working correctly. Some number won't pass the check because of [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) but usually, you will get way more numbers than you want.

So what you need to do is just checking that after the sqrt the result is an int:

```
if (sqrootd % 1 == 0) { ... }
```

An optimization you can do is to check the number is an integer before sqrt.
 
Other than that, your code looks fine to me

Comment: what is `variable`?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sorry, is sqroot

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I got a downvote and an upvote, so there must be something wrong I guess

Comment: no upvote, no downvote - probably it was revoked, that is, it must have **been** something wrong (the smiley at my comment should suggest it was not that serious  [:-))

Comment: must be that then

Comment: You can also use `if ((int) sqroot == sqroot)` !  Is it a good idea?  Probably not. (Especially for doubles higher than int max)

Comment: The posted link (rounding, precision lost, ...) is hardly the reason for it not working: OP is using `double` **and** not checking that it is an integer (reason why I asked him/her for exact definition)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I thought of that reason too but this will also fix it. and in theory, this might be an issue

Comment: one of many many  solutions.... (despite the result (in this case) is almost obvious straight-forward `132.5` [:-) )

Comment: The output is now 121 so I think this pretty much did it, but could you clarify what you mean by checking the number is an integer, for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following mathematical formula to find the perfect square:

1 + 3 + 5 + 7 .... = n ^ 2

for example: 1 + 3 + 5 = 9 = 3 ^ 2

and sample code:

```
   int i = 1;

    while (num > 0) {
        num = num - i;
        i = i + 2;
    }

    return num == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if square root is an integer you will need below condition

```
if ((sqroot - Math.floor(sqroot)) == 0){
```

instead of

```
if(sqroot*sqroot == num){
```

The Math.sqrt() method finds the square root of the given number and the floor() method finds the largest (closest to positive infinity) floating-point value that less than or equal to the argument (here square root value returned by sqrt() method) and is equal to a mathematical integer.

Then we calculate the difference between these two to check if the difference is zero. For a perfect square number this difference is always zero. The reason is: square root of perfect square number is integer.

[reference](https://beginnersbook.com/2019/02/java-program-to-check-if-given-number-is-perfect-square/)

Comment: I think you explained the functionality of `round()` not `floor()` - it is not the "closest integer", more the largest integer that is less or equal to the given number

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thanks for pointing it out. you are right. I will update the answer